# Differentiation between query executed on on demand pricing and flat rate pricing in bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In GCP bigquery, there are two types of pricing 1) On demand 2) Flat rate pricing.

I have two projects one is configured with on-demand, other one is configured with flat rate pricing. Now when i executes a query on two projects, i need to know the differentiation between the query executed on on-demand pricing and flat rate pricing. In the GUI, we can know the difference .

**Flat Rate Pricing**

[image]

**On demand pricing**

[image]

But through bigquery libraries i am calling the bigquery [API](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/main/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/GetJob.java) to get the job Object by jobId. In that i am unable to find the difference between those queries , atleast i expected some info related to [reservation](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/JobStatistics.ReservationUsage.html) in the flat rate pricing query, but there is no luck. I need this info in our monitoring tool to identify the difference between the queries that are executed on on-demand and flat rate.

One analysis i found was through information schema we can get the info, but i am more interested at the API level through bigquery java libraries.

Comment: The information should be here: `select * from \`region-us\`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS where date(creation_time)>current_date()-2`

Comment: Thanks for the comment samuel, since i am using the API layer through google cloud libraries, i don't want to touch the information schema . It will be like adding another datasource for my project. It will be better if i get that info through those libraries only. Atleast if i get some hint like this query was executed through reservation then may be i can add this datasource, but that is also not coming through those API's

Answer (score 1):

In the [Get job API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/get), you get a JOB object. In it, you have a JobStatistic entry. In this entry, you have the reservation detail

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer blaquiere, but when i hit that API using google cloud libraries by the jobId of query which was executed on flat rate pricing . I am getting that object as null. That's the issue

Comment: Did you try to get the object AFTER the job ends? I suspect that the API wait for job completion to populate that field. But if it's the case, it won't help your use case....

Comment: Yeah, i tried that only after the job completion, i waited for long time to check that case also, but it didn't helped